# Defining Projection Lambert Conformal Conical w custom GCS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, mexico

I have a shapefile from Mexico´s INEGI site that doesn´t have a .prj file.  I am having trouble defining the projection in ArcGIS.  INEGI tells me it is projected as Lambert Conformal Conical with a ITRF92 GCS.  From what I understand, this GCS should be the same as WGS84 (I have used this with other INEGI files and it matched).  This combination of LCC & WGS84 doesn't exist in ESRI´s system, so I tried to create a custom projection coordinate system with the following information given by INEGI:

```
longitude of origin: -102.0, 
latitude of origin: 12.0, 
standard parallel 1: 17.5,
standard parallel 2: 29.5, 
false easting: 2500000.0 m, 
false northing: 0.0 m
```

But this doesn´t work - ArcGIS puts the file in Africa, not Mexico (though it seems to be the right scale).

I´m wondering if there is something going wrong with the GCS, for which INEGI gives this information:

```
Datum: ITRF92
Sphereoid: GRS80
Semimajor axis: 6378206.4  
Inverse Flattening 294.9786982
```

These numbers are not the same as ESRI´s WGS84 or ITRF92, and I can´t figure out how to change them in the "Define Projection" tool.

This is the link to the site that contains the data: http://www.inegi.org.mx/geo/contenidos/recnat/edafologia/vectorial_serieii.aspx

At the bottom are the links to the date, I downloaded "Perfiles de Suelo".

The extent of the data is:

```
Top -2347872.613848
Bottom -340538.708859
Left -1075400.666415
Right  - 4073175.438209
```

The data is supposed to cover the nation of Mexico.

Comment: The spheroid/ellipsoid parameters are for Clarke 1866 which would have been used for NAD27, not ITRF92/WGS84. Would you please add to your question the extent of the shapefile, plus the area that it represents (if the extent isn't lat/lon)? A link to the data if it's available would be useful too.

Comment: Thanks @mkennedy, and apologies for the delay.  I am in an area with spotty internet.  I´ve added the information to my question. I am completely confused and don´t understand why it would have the parameters for Clarke 1866!

Answer (score 1):

This coordinate system is [EPSG:6362](http://epsg.io/6362) and the coordinate system is found in ArcMap under `Projected Coordinate Systems -> National Grids -> North America`

Considering the False Easting for this projection is 2.5 million meters, the extent of your data seems incorrect.